# Spelling not working in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, language, spell-check

I'm running 60.3.3 (32-bit) on 64-bit Windows 8.1. According to `Tool > Options > Advanced > Update` this is the latest 32-bit version.

Spelling using English (UK), or indeed any other language, just will not work as I write an email.

During composition, `Options > Check Spelling` displays no dictionary.
[image: Options > Check Spelling]

From the main Mozilla interface, `Tools > Options > Spelling` shows no listed dictionaries and when I select `Download More Dictionaries`, all "English (GB) Language Pack" versions state "This add-on is not compatible with your version of Thunderbird." (including older versions).

If I choose the `Add-Ons` version for "British English Dictionary (Marco Pinto) v2.70", this claims to be compatible and after installation (either automatically or using the manual method), the dictionary is listed as an Add-on.

[image: English dictionary add-on]

Why is this not working?

Comment: I don't know what went wrong, so I suggest uninstalling and reinstalling Thunderbird. Be careful to first save your profile in `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird\Profiles`.

Comment: @harrymc: Naturally I'm a little nervous about such a drastic step! Will this save all the many email accounts, sub-folders, filters, addresses, etc? Should I install the 64-bit version afterwards or stick with the 32-bit version?

Comment: This how I transfer my Thunderbird accounts to a new computer. Just remember to transfer the *contents* of the folder, since a new installation will give another name to the profile. Make a backup of everything before, also of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird` and of `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Thunderbird`. You may also take a backup image of the system disk, if you like. And, yes, you are right to be nervous, because nothing is guaranteed. I hope that by copying the profile you won't be propagating the problem.

Comment: @harrymc: I wrote to Marco Pinto (who wrote the British UK spell-checker) and he pointed out that his version only works in v60.5.x TB (not 60.3.3). TB itself does not tell me there is a new version, but when I installed v60.5.2 (the latest x86 version), it all started working as Marco said it would! Will update the answer with this information.

Comment: TB gives all that information when a new version is installed. It's a good idea to read it before hitting OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developer of the British English spell-checker (Marco Pinto) has confirmed privately that the checker has been converted to a WebExtension which only works on v60.5.x (and does NOT work on 60.3.3).

Thunderbird itself does not find this version, but if you go to the [official Thunderbird website](https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/releases/), v60.5.2 is available. After download, exit Thunderbird, instal the new version (over the top of the old version), restart Thunderbird, and spell-checking has started working!